# How to convert Double to String with exponential sign

Tags: java, number-formatting

I want to convert a Double to String with exponential signs in it.
For example, Double value is `4.4395749E7` after converting to String it should be `4.4395749E+07` (Same as how it shows in MS Excel).

I have tried `double.toString()`, but it is converting to `4.4395749E7`:

```
Double doubleValue = 44395749d;
doubleValue.toString();
```

Expected is `4.4395749E+07`, but actual is `4.4395749E7`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expected that; you're getting the standard Java double string conversion. Easiest is to just split and add the extra digits, although there's probably a library to do this out there.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you want exactly. Are you saying the E should be followed with the sign of the exponent and 2 significant figures always? What if it is greater than 2 significant figures? In any case, if you're looking to write the output into an excel spreadsheet, I suggest looking into the Apache POI library. It is likely much easier in the long term than copying and pasting, which is what it seems you intend to do.

Answer (score 2):

you can use String.format(), `E` is the format code for exponentials

```
Double doubleValue = 44395749d;
System.out.println(String.format("%E", doubleValue));
```

Comment: This will cut of the last fraction digit to `4.439575E+07` instead of `4.4395749E+07`. Maybe it is also useful to mention the locale parameter (`String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%E", value)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format your number:

```
Double value = 44395749d;
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
if (value > 1 || value < -1) {
    symbols.setExponentSeparator("E+");
}
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0E00", symbols);
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(value));
```

This uses `DecimalFormatSymbols` to add the `+` for the exponent if needed (`value > 1` or `value < -1`). To get all fraction digits use `setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`. You can simply change the format if needed.

The result will be `4.4395749E+07`.

Bare in mind to set a specific locale if needed:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
```